# Calculated Field Data Type in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

On the datasheet view, I need to combine the values from fields that have more than 255 characters into a single field(column).  The calculated field truncates the result!

Is there a way to create a Calculated Field with a Long Text data type?  If not, what are the best alternatives to get the same result?

Comment: how do you combine the fields in your calculated field? do you store the result in another field?

Comment: Do this in a query.

Comment: As June said concatenate the values in a query and union with an empty dummy table like described here http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

Comment: Thank you!  I solved it with a SQL query with UNION ALL

Comment: @PHerzog Post this as answer (don't forget to format the query-string properly).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all!

Here was the query I used:

```sql
SELECT 
    [HISTORY A-J].CONTACTID, 
    [HISTORY A-J].[ClientView Note] 
FROM 
    [HISTORY A-J] 
WHERE 
    (False)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    [HISTORY A-J].CONTACTID, 
    [HISTORY A-J].[Created On] & " " & [HISTORY A-J].X_TypeName & " " & [HISTORY A-J].Regarding & " " & [HISTORY A-J].Details & " " & [HISTORY A-J].Attachment_Display & " " & [HISTORY A-J].Attachment_Path & " " & [HISTORY A-J].Attachment_FileName AS Result 
FROM 
    [HISTORY A-J];
```

Comment: How to: [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and  [Format SQL](http://poorsql.com/) ;)